# Data transformation in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a windows application, I have a table that I grab from oracle. After reading the table,I need to transform some column values to some other values.for example:

table FruitbyDate

```
Fruit       Fruitdate    
Apple       6/4/15 
Pearl       6/6/15
Kiwi        6/20/15
Watermelon  6/9/15
```

I want to transform the fruit from text to int( apple =1, pearl =2, kiwi=3, watermelon=4) and update the table to :

```
Fruit       Fruitdate    
1           6/4/15 
2           6/6/15
3           6/20/15
4           6/9/15
```

I'm beginner of C# wanting to get an idea of how to transform and update the table in oracle. I only learned the basic of Enumerations. But not enough knowledge of updating each record from name to number and string to int. Thanks!

Comment: Simply listing your requirements and asking for help is not a good way to ask a question on this site. Please see [Why is "Can someone Help me" not an "actual" question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work.

Comment: I think it's reasonably clear what the OP requires. What might help is more context about what kind of app this is to be used in.

Comment: I hope I make it more clear. Please let me know if this is acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is the Strategy Pattern.  A very simple way of implementing this would be to simply use a `Dictionary<string, int>`.  For example, you might have something like this:

```
static Dictionary<string, int> fruitDict = new Dictionary<string, int>
{
    { "Apple", 1 },
    { "Pear", 2 } // etc.
};
```

You could then iterate through the rows of your `DataTable` (or pull from your `DataReader`), and return the lookup:

```
myFruitVariable[currentIndex] = fruitDict[row["Fruit"]];
```

Note that you should check to make sure that your `fruitDict` `ContainsKey()` before doing the lookup.

There are more elaborate ways of handling this with the Strategy pattern, but a Dictionary probably should suffice here.

Comment: This is a better answer than mine if your list of fruits can grow dynamically (maybe it's specified in another database table?). If it's more fixed then the Enum method might be better.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like you've got a classic case for an `enum`. Here's some sample code to get you started (difficult to say more without knowing for example whether this is a console app, or an ASP.Net website etc.):

```
public enum FruitType
{
  Unknown = 0,
  Apple = 1,
  Pearl = 2,
  Kiwi = 3,
  Watermelon = 4
}

// RawData has the fruit names as strings
// FruitInformation is the transformed value you're trying to create
public IEnumerable<FruitInformation> ProcessFruits(IEnumerable<RawData> rawData)
{
  var result = new List<FruitInformation>();
  foreach (var entry in rawData)
  {
    FruitType parsedFruit;
    if (!Enum.TryParse(typeof(FruitType), entry.fruit, out parsedFruit))
    {
      parsedFruit = FruitType.Unknown;
    }
    result.Add(new FruitInformation(parsedFruit, entry.FruitDate));
  }
  return result;
}
```